# Disabling event listeners when switching views in large backbone js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am developing a large single page Backbone JS application. I have several views  that consists of a large div, when the user navigates to a specific hash location the backbone router loads the view, which basically triggers an event "show" on the specific backbone view and it unloads all the other views and $(this.el) becomes visible.

Basically in the end I'll end up with several hundered views that when switching between them does the same thing, hides the active views div, and shows the next one corresponding to the link you clicked (Links are all hashtag locations).

Is there any benefit to disabling or undelegating the events of the views that are inactive/hiden? Right now all of the views are already instantiated and ready to trigger the "show" or "hide" event, but I am thinking that it might be more memory/performance effective to just disable all DOM-related events on views that are hidden, and unbind the models or collections that the hidden view is using as well.

I was thinking of having a "cleanup" trigger that fires when a user switches from an active view to a new one, that disables all events and then hiding the div, but is it necessary, or is there a better way of doing this, reducing memory usage and increasing performance?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use for this is keeping only one view of a kind in DOM. I.e:

Let's say we got 3 views:

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#main-view',

  events: {
    "click .openView1":   "openView1",
    "click .openView2":   "openView2"
  },

  render: function() {
    //...
  },

  openView1: {
      this.activeView = new View1();
  },

  openView2: {
      this.activeView = new View2();
  }
});

var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({
});

var View2 = Backbone.View.extend({
});
```

you shouldn't have memory problems when you save active view in one variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely unbind all events in your views that are hidden or never needed anymore. Think about a view that binds to model or collection. The view is not visible and something changed in the model. Now the views updates its DOM although the change will not visible.

Unbinding DOM events only make sense when you delete a view, so the garbage collector can remove the DOM element. If it has still binded events it can result in memory leaks.

Take a look at the way the [Marionette](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html) framework handles this. In the [`close`](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html#section-20) method of a view, it unbinds all events that was binded to models/collections and unbinds all events to the DOM.

You should also think about if you really wanna save that much views. Its not about memory problems that you will get. Its about the consistence hell. You have to make sure that all your views get all changes of your models and update them self even if they not visible. Working on some larger single page apps, I can say that it's much better to rerender your views then to save them.